# Is there a way to export your Pocket favorites?

Tags: pocket

Is there a way to export all your favorites from Pocket? Preferably to PDF.

Answer (score 8):

They provide the following tool (https://getpocket.com/export) to export all your articles to HTML, neatly grouped by unread/read. The tags and the timestamp at which the article was added are present as attributes on the links.

The problem is that there is no way to find what are the favorites.

For that you will have to use their [API](https://getpocket.com/developer/docs/v3/retrieve), that supports retrieving only the favorites. Or you could bulk-tag your favorites with a "favorite" tag, and use this tag when exporting to html.

Comment: Interesting. I couldn't find a link anywhere on my Pocket account to an export feature.

Comment: I'm not sure that @cregox is spam, the kiwi browser is indeed a recognized alternative to Chrome on mobile. When I want to use addons while on the phone, I use kiwi myself.

Comment: @nicolaswebdev what do you mean? did i have written anything here that got marked and removed?! 

Answer (score -1):

If you use Chrome, once you go to the favourites page (https://getpocket.com/a/favorites/list/), press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and in *Destination* choose **Save as PDF**.

Comment: Does this print all of the Favourite article themselves to one PDF, or does it just print out the web-page of the list of articles at it appears on screen?

Comment: This does not work at all. It only prints the few favorites that are loaded, and it's covered up by a big menu.